# How do I upgrade my AWS EC2 instance using the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to increase the number of CPU cores in my EC2 instance, using the AWS CLI.

My instance is currently a C5.4 Large.

I don't know the command for this, and I don't know if I have to know the instance type I want to switch to beforehand, or if I can browse different instance types from the AWS CLI.

Answer (score 2):

`aws ec2 help` lists the commands `describe-instances`, `stop-instances`, `modify-instance-attribute`, and `start-instances`.

Calling `aws ec2`[`describe-instances`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) may provide too much information. You can select the fields you would like with the `--query` option. `--query` takes a "JMESPath", which stands for "JSON Matching Expression paths" - a set of special syntaxes for getting values out of complicated JSON.<sup>1</sup>

You need enough information to identify the instance, for example, its name and type. Start the JMESPath with `Reservations[*].Instances[*]`, followed by `[InstanceId, InstanceType, KeyName]`.<sup>2</sup>

Example:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, InstanceType, KeyName]' \
--region us-east-1
```

Copy the ID.

Stop the instance before upgrading it:

```
aws ec2 stop-instances \
--instance-ids "$INSTANCE_ID"
```

It can take 5-10 minutes for it to stop.

Change the instance type with `modify-instance-attribute`:

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute \
--instance-id "$INSTANCE_ID" \
--instance-type "{\"Value\":\"$REQUESTED_TYPE\"}
```

Replace `$REQUESTED_TYPE` with the name of a type, for example, `t2.small`.<sup>3</sup>

There may be limitations on what kinds of instances are allowed for your account, so make sure it's an instance type you have access to.

Now, restart the instance and you're done:

```
aws ec2 start-instances \
--instance-ids "$INSTANCE_ID"
```

You'll have to wait a few minutes before the instance has finished booting up.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> [Here](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) is a tutorial on using JMESPath.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Every time you call an `ec2` command, it is important to specify the region with the option `--region`. If you don't query a specific region, you won't see your instances.</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup> (The quotes are escaped with a backslash so your shell doesn't misinterpret them.)</sup>

Comment: FYI, JMESPath was written by James Saryerwinnie, so there's probably some additional meaning to the name! :)